# Hibernate: Refreshing parent of many-to-one

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I have two classes: `Parent` and `Child`, mapped one-to-many with relationship owned by `Child`. I also am using 2nd level cache with Ehcache.

To persist the relationship, I do this:

```
child.setParent(parent);
session.saveOrUpdate(child);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
```

When I load `parent` in another session (from 2nd level cache), will this newly added `child` be visible? What is the proper way to refresh parent's collection in this situation?

Bonus points for answers that have some concrete explanation or link to docs, not "seems fine to me, yes".

To be clear: Everything happens inside a transaction that is properly committed. The main question is: **Is this the right way to refresh `parent.children` for this `Session` and for others in 2nd level cache?**

Another point: **What shall I do to evict such collection from 2nd level cache on rollback?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this is because of the nature of database isolation, things that are not committed should not be visible to other database connection (in Hibernate language, things that are not committed should not be visible to other Hibernate sessions).
What you need to do to be visible in other Hibernate sessions is to commit the transaction (in Hibernate language, commit the Hibernate session).

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()

child.setParent(parent);
session.saveOrUpdate(child);
parent.getChildren().add(child);

tx.commit()
```

I quote from [this documentation site](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow)

In unmanaged context:

> You do not have to flush() the Session
>   explicitly: the call to commit()
>   automatically triggers the
>   synchronization depending on the
>   FlushMode for the session. A call to
>   close() marks the end of a session.
>   The main implication of close() is
>   that the JDBC connection will be
>   relinquished by the session. This Java
>   code is portable and runs in both
>   non-managed and JTA environments.

Answer (score 0):

What type of cache do you use?

This sequence works fine for me:

```
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
session.saveOrUpdate(child);
session.flush();
```

Also, make sure that you REALLY need that cache. In my experience, 2-nd level cache rarely accelerates real applications and yet creates a lot of problems.

Comment: It's replicated Ehcache. Not sure what you mean by type. Will your solution work if I load the entity one minute later from 2nd level cache in another session, on another server?

Answer (score 0):

It will be visible if you are using Eager loading..

For Lazy loading you need to initialize it:

```
Parent p = em.find(Parent.class, 1);
Hibernate.initialize(p);
System.out.println(p.child);
```

More info about it can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the cache strategy you choosed for this parent.children collection (READ_ONLY, NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE...) . If it's not READ_ONLY and the persist of child is done correctly,  hibernate will evict the collection from the 2nd level cache.